# Why am i being told that my array is not identified?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am writing a function, where I input a string and the function checks it's position in the array. I have writen the code, but i keep getting an error and the console says "contents[i] not identified" but i already defined the array.

```
function idxP1(contents,pattern) {

var contents = [ "Loughborough University offers degree programmes and 
world class research.", "An alternative University", "Yet another 
University"];

return contents.findIndex(word => word.toLowerCase().includes(pattern));


}
alert(idxP1(null, 'Uni'))
```

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: The loop will always end at the first iteration returning either `0` or `-1`. The first parameter has the same name as the variable you're declaring in the function.

Comment: So do I have to set a different variable, then let them equal each other?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: The problem is you have a semicolon at the end of the for line, so i is always equal to 3 and contents[3] is not defined.

Comment: i removed the semi colon but am still being told that contents[i] is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments you should definitely use `findIndex`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

```js
function idxP1(contents, pattern) {
  var contents = ["Loughborough University offers degree programmes and world class research.", "An alternative University", "Yet another University"];
  return contents.findIndex(word => word.toLowerCase().includes(pattern.toLowerCase()));
}

console.log(idxP1(null, 'Uni'));
```

Note: Thanks to @Andreas & @Keith for their comments

**Edit: Added a runnable code snippet**

Comment: I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: word.toLowerCase(...).contains is not a function"

Comment: I added a runnable code snippet + modified the code from `contains` to `includes`. (`contains` has been removed from firefox since v48 and has been replaced by `includes`

Comment: I tried this, but i got the output as -1 which is incorrect.

Comment: I don't understand, did you try to run the snippet ? The output is `0`.

Comment: yeah, but when I try to alert the output I get an error for some reason :/

Comment: Can you edit your question in order for me to see what is your code ?

Comment: Ok it didn't work at first because of the return line added by stackoverflow when there are too many character in one line. Can you try to reformat ? Where do you test ? You can directly test it in the Chrome Console if needed

Comment: oh nevermind, i made a type-o :D. Thank you very much

Comment: Great then ! Feel free to ask any other question again in stackoverflow :)